# Methane and wetlands

Tags: biochemistry, soil

Some papers I have read show carbon accumulation (peat) in wetlands is reduced because of low methane emissions. Why is this the case?

Why does low methane emission reduce carbon accumulation in wetlands?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Could you provide the links to the papers you read?